# Netplan configuration error: "Invalid YAML ... did not find expected key."

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ip, static-ip

I'm trying to connect to internet using static IP, but when I enter `sudo netplan apply` command, the console returns the following error:

```
Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 8 column 5: did not find expected key.
```

How to fix this? The content of my `01-netcfg.yaml` looks like:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp0s3:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [10.0.2.15/64]
            gateway4: 10.0.2.0
            nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: Just going to point out a few things, your entire network config is fubar.  /64 isn't a valid IPv4 CIDR, 10.0.2.0 isn't a valid gateway, and you also really need to learn how YAML works - specifically its indentation.  My answer covers all these specific bits.  And since this is *your* network, you need to either know these settings, or contact your network administrator(s) to know what the gateway and CIDR range are supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

So, with regards to the specific error you're getting, you've failed basic YAML syntax and indentation, which is one of the reasons `netplan` is complaining.  YAML is **extremely** indentation-oriented for how it interprets commands, config arguments, etc.  You need to have proper indentation for YAML configs to be parsed.  Surprise, you aren't doing that at all, and breaking YAML syntax.  That's why `netplan` is complaining because you aren't providing proper YAML.

But even *more importantly* than the YAML syntax which will make Netplan work, ***you have some critical failures with your network configuration***, and you really need to fix these regardless.  These failures are, specifically:

- `10.0.2.15/64` is not a valid IPv4 CIDR range.  The acceptable CIDR ranges are between `/0` (for all IPv4) and `/32` (for a single address) for IPv4.  Most networks are `/24` for the CIDR range (with this IP range, that would encompass `10.0.2.1 - 10.0.2.255` as usable address space, though I would assume the `.1` is the Gateway and the `.255` is the Broadcast, but that might differ in your network so double check all the values!).  The proper CIDR range is needed so the system knows what its netmask and reachable IP space is.
- `10.0.2.0` isn't a proper gateway address.  The `.0` address is not a usable address in IP subnetting, as it's usually held by the network prefix alone.  And since your netowrk config attempts to do a `/24` but horrendously fails, this gateway should probably be `10.0.2.1` - but again, double check these values with your network admin first.

So, fixing your indentation *and* fixing the network to assume it's a `/24` based on the attempted IP and gateway you specified, your YAML should look like the below, with the proper indentations.  And compared to your existing one, you *really* need to learn how indentation works.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.0.2.15/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: @user9507446 if this fixes the issues and fixes your network, consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox underneath the voting buttons.  That will mark the question as solved/answered.  Note that you should only do that if you actually don't get any other errors or such.  Also note that network configuration errors such as incorrect IP addresses or IP ranges is not covered here, because I'm not the admin of your network.

Comment: Now I get `Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 16: mapping values are not allowed in this context`. Could it mean that I'm using the incorrect IP?

Comment: @user9507446 Put the YAML you're trying to use in a pastebin at https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and then provide the link to that here in another comment.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gv6nsYNnxY/

Comment: @user9507446 Line 13 of that config doesn't match the proper syntax for the `addresses` line - go compare what you've got to what my answer has.

Comment: Fixed, but I now get the same error in line 9.

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me:

```
 network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.2/24
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.0.1
                - 8.8.8.8
                search:
                - workgroup
    version: 2
```

then followed these commands:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Hope it does for you too.

Comment: This worked for me and gave me what i needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to configure netplan, using guides like the one above and the following:

- [Configure Static IP Addresses On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/)
- [How to configure a static IP address in Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/)
- [How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

  ... but I found it easier to remove nplan completely and do [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces) and the solution that works straight away, gets the job done with the least hassle is always going to be the one I use, rather than something new, which is more convoluted and annoying.

Answer (score -1):

When I edited the `.yaml` file and executed: 
`$ netplan try`  it failed.

In my case I could solve it leaving the space that had the original file: This is on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LST. Backup the original file before edit it. Good luck.

[image]