# Invalid YAML for netplan: mapping values

Tags: 18.04, netplan, static-ip

So, I am trying to set a static IP address for my Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS. I
took the ethernet config from [this
site](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html).

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
        nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]
```

I carefully made sure there a space between each colon, didn't use tabs and made
sure there's no leading spaces at the end of each line. Yet, when I run
`netplan --debug generate`, I get:

```
Invalid YAML at /etc/netplan/01-network-card.yaml line 9 column 19: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Then, I compared the config with some other sample configs
([1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033633/794515),
[2](https://netplan.io/examples#dhcp-and-static-addressing), [3](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089993/794515)) and didn't notice
much difference.

I also tried putting the addresses as:

```
addresses: [ "192.168.0.1/24" ]
```

As seen in [this config](https://netplan.io/examples#vlans) with no luck. Whatever I try, it seems that the `gateway4` line is always the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's the indentation of `nameservers` that's the problem, I think?

Comment: Ohh, so I guess it thought `nameservers` was part of that same line. Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested why you are assigning `enp3s0` the same IP address as the gateway is using.

Answer (score 1):

Add space using the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, not <kbd>tab</kbd> in above-mentioned line.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I see it as a valid (if short) answer.