# Invalid YAML: mapping values are not allowed in this context: network:

Tags: networking, server, netplan, static-ip

I'm trying to configure a static IP and I keep getting this error when I try and execute the changes:

```
Invalid YAML: mapping values are not allowed in this context:
network:
       ^
```

I've edited my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to:

```
network:
 version: 2
 ethernets:
  eno1:
   dhcp4: false
   addresses: [192.168.20.6/24]
   gateway4: 192.168.20.2
   nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,192.168.20.2]
```

I [used this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-desktop-server) for this configuration, but I've also followed a bunch of other guides and each time with same result.

All [the](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113993/invalid-yaml-for-netplan-mapping-values) other questions I've read that are related to this issue have been some problem to do with incorrect indentation or spacing, but I can't see where I'm going wrong. I've followed a few different examples, and have rewritten the file several times to try and make sure I'm not missing a stray spaces but I'm getting the same result every time.

Comment: Does adding `--debug` to the `netplan apply` command provide any useful information?

Comment: @steeldriver, using `--debug` still gave me the same error message but made me go back and look at the `network` line. I was missing the `#` to comment the developer credit which I didn't notice because I was so focussed on looking for spaces that I didn't notice it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` should look like this. Netplan is very fussy about formatting. Use my .yaml EXACTLY as I show it.

- 2 space indentation
- no tabs
- added "renderer: networkd"
- "dhcp4: false" is not required, as false is the default
- brackets around [192.168.20.6/24]
- spaces after commas in nameservers addresses

---

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [192.168.20.6/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.20.2
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 192.168.20.2]
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made those changes but it turned out I hadn't commented out the developers credit in the first line, which fixed it

Comment: @Sebr You didn't show that in your example .yaml file. What did it say?

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry. It said `# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'`. I'm new to Linux so I didn't notice that it wasn't commented out and didn't think it was relevant

Comment: @Sebr Correct analysis! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your yaml file is invalid for exactly the reason you suspected: indentation and spacing. Your file says, in part:

```
network:
 version: 2
 ethernets:
  eno1:
```

Notice that the indentation is one space below *network:*. Compare the supplied templates:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

Which says, in part:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
```

Notice that the indentation is, in every case (except *nameservers*), two spaces. I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.20.6/24
      gateway4: 192.168.20.2
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,192.168.20.2]
```

Netplan is also very specific in that it allows spaces in the file and not tabs. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Please see: https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: This comment didn't answer my problem, but that link was really useful as someone who's new to Linux and found it hard to get clear and simple information on setting up a static IP