# Slave nics in a bond are getting an IP from DHCP, despite netplan config?

Tags: server, netplan, network-bonding

I'm on Ubuntu Server 19.10, using netplan, and I have 4 bonded nics in a balance-rr bond.  It is configured in Netplan as a static IP.  After applying netplan or rebooting I cannot ping the gateway.  When I run "ip a" I can see my 4 slave nics and my bond, however the slave nics have an IP on my guest subnet from DHCP.  When I run a ping at the gateway, I'm getting destination unreachable but the source IP is the DHCP one, not my static bonded IP.  Cloud-init is not in play; it is not installed and neither is network manager.  This is a similar issue to this one: [Configure bonded 802.3ad network using netplan on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033847/configure-bonded-802-3ad-network-using-netplan-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I have tried many configurations, but this is what I'm working off of now: https://gist.github.com/PhilipSchmid/54e17f53c15e3bd2c922ec6ff9ee434f

Here is my /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:

```
network: 
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1: 
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
    eno2: 
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
    eno3: 
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
    eno4: 
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
```

Here is my /etc/netplan/02-bondings.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 10.1.2.10/16
      gateway4: 10.1.1.1
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
        - eno3
        - eno4
      nameservers:
        addresses: 
          - 127.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
        search:
          - domain.com
      parameters:
        mode: balance-rr
```

After applying that (with debug, no errors) I get the following when I run "ip a"

```
root@hostname:/etc/netplan# ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mo master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:98:f1:5b:59:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
    inet 10.1.100.38/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mo master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:98:f1:5b:59:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.100.38/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eno2
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mo master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:98:f1:5b:59:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.100.38/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eno3
        valid_ift forever preferred_lft forever 
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:98:f1:5b:59:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.100.38/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eno4
        valid_ift forever preferred_lft forever 
6: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:98:f1:5b:59:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.2.10/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global bondo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:07:ff:se:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172. 17.255.255 scope global docker0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I do "ping -4 -I bond0 10.1.1.1" I can ping the gateway, so it seems like a default route issue...so why is dhcp active on my slave nics?  It's explicitly disabled?

I'm stumped, any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In this line of output:

```
inet 10.1.100.38/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
```

Notably, the `dynamic` flag is NOT set.  So whatever is configuring this address on your system, it is neither `NetworkManager` nor `networkd` (the two netplan backends), since both of those network configurators will correctly set the `dynamic` flag.

So something else, outside of netplan, appears to be running on your system and configuring addresses on your interfaces.  You would have to locally investigate what, since it's not a component of the default Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 1):

I found it; I had installed a desktop environment (MATE to use as a remote x2go endpoint) and though I removed NetworkManager I didn't know that dhcpcd had been enabled.  I disabled that and I was good to go.  Nothing in the config had indicated that dhcpcd was in play so it was nasty to troubleshoot, I hope this can help someone else out in the future.