# No network after installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have been having trouble installing ubuntu network for my server Dell R610. My knowledge regarding server is pretty low and I do pray to everything that someone would be able to help me here!

I currently have 5 network ports as you can see in the following picture:

[image: server]

When I tried to install Ubuntu, it said that I did not had any connection during the installment and I skipped the part. Then once I accessed the server I started by doing `ping google.com` which returned `"Network is unreachable"`
I thjen checked my ip addr and tried to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwXDzsVY8-4 and my setup ended up looking like this:

[image]
[image: Pic 2]

After that I saved by doing CTRL + S and then netplan apply. I tried to ping google again and still I reached the `"Network is unreachable"`. The network cable was connected to the port that says GB 1.

Now I still do not have any network and I have no idea what to do, I hope someone could be my angel and help me out from here ! :'(

Comment: The port on the back at the far left is the iDRAC or Remote Management port.  I honestly though haven't had much success with netplan and bonding.  Even in the data center I work in we don't use netplan.  You're more than welcome to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293208/cant-disable-local-addresses-on-network-interfaces/1293486#1293486 my answer there.  Since the R610 has 2x1Gb and 2x10Gb ports and if you bond them make sure you are bonding  and if I remember right the 10Gb are the inner 2 ports, but it has been a while since I have worked on a R610.

Comment: If bonding to use the matching speed ports I mean.