# Network bonding: slave NICs still get DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-bonding

I'm setting up bonding of two 1 GB Ethernet NICs on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS in mode 0 (balanced-rr).

The bond is working in that it comes up at the assigned IP address and I can SSH into it at this address.  However, each of the bonded slave NICs still get a DHCP address assigned.

How can I set this up so only the bond has an IP address?

Here's how I set it up:

```
sudo apt-get install ifenslave
sudo modprobe bonding
Edited /etc/modules to add "bonding"
```

Finally, edited /etc/network/interfaces to contain the following:
(Note, it was blank before I edited it)

```
# bond0 is the bonded NIC, can be used like a normal NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
  address 10.16.0.91
  gateway 10.16.0.1
  netmask 255.255.0.0

  #mode 0 is balanced-rr
  bond-mode 0
  bond-miimon 100
  bond-slaves enp1s0 enp2s0

# enp1s0 connected to bond0
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual
  bond-master bond0

# enp2s0 connected to bond0
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual
 bond-master bond0
```

After rebooting, when I do "ifconfig" it gives the following (and I can use all 3 IPs)

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.16.0.91  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.16.255.255
        inet6 fe80::203:2dff:fe41:edae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:03:2d:41:ed:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 356  bytes 29976 (29.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 110  bytes 16969 (16.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.16.100.143  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.16.255.255
        ether 00:03:2d:41:ed:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 252  bytes 23651 (23.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 8779 (8.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x91300000-913fffff

enp2s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.16.100.142  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.16.255.255
        ether 00:03:2d:41:ed:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 240  bytes 19975 (19.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75  bytes 12250 (12.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x91100000-911fffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 85  bytes 6400 (6.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 85  bytes 6400 (6.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How do I prevent the slave interfaces from getting their own DHCP address?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Terrance.  Unfortunately, it doesn't - the system doesn't have dhcpcd (there is not a /etc/dhcpcd.conf file.)  I looked to see if there is a way to do something similar using /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf but it didn't appear so.

Comment: Maybe look at the answer here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293208/cant-disable-local-addresses-on-network-interfaces/1293486#1293486  Possible that netplan.io is still there causing some issues?

Comment: I'm not using netplan.  (The only updates to the networking after the Ubuntu server install are those above.)  In that linked question, the Answer "Feb. 25, 2021 Note:" it seems the final solution was for DHCPCD, editing the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file again.

Comment: I wrote that answer, but I also removed Netplan.io from the system to stop conflicting with ifupdown.  I wasn't using netplan either, but it was there causing issues as well.

Comment: I see.  Removing netplan.io did indeed fix the issue!  It also seems to have removed an irritating wait on network configuration that was causing the boot to take a lot longer.  @Terrance you sir are a gentleman and a scholar!  Thank you.

Comment: Let me write that up here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to be using `ifupdown` for controlling your network cards, the application of `netplan.io` is no longer needed.  It will conflict with `ifupdown` causing issues of extra IP addresses, etc.

```
sudo apt remove netplan.io
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that wants to remove ubuntu-minimal as well,  which sounds important, can netplan.io be removed in 22.04?

Comment: @teknopaul I don't have it installed on my 22.04, but I don't remember it asking to remove ubuntu-minimal.  It only removed the netplan.io for me.  Then again, when I upgraded to 22.04 I can't remember if netplan.io was even installed.