# ubuntu 18.04, activation of network connection failed

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, ethernet, connection, wired

Had 16.04 version earlier and some update corrupted my network configuration. 
Screwed up trying to repair it as suggested  in stackexchange and ended up deleting the manager.

Had to freshly install 18.04 by wiping out the complete data and still I get the message that **the activation of network connection failed**.

Tried almost all the solutions from askubuntu and other forums but in vain... please help

Comment: This site works best if you provide us with your issue (with detail) and resulting errors, and then we provide answers, or at minimum what you've tried to follow.  I'd suggest looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces/1031737#1031737 as so far you've only told us *it doesn't work*

Comment: There is a range of answers concerning 18.04 also at https://askubuntu.com/q/1062390/446253