# Network Unreachable - Ethernet

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, connection

I'm trying to get my new Ubuntu Server install connected to the internet, but Im running into an issue. I cant even ping the router that the server is directly plugged into via Ethernet. I've tried looking at a number of forums and setting the OS to use DHCP, setting static IPs, etc. And now I am here. Hoping that someone can point out where my problem lies.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu Server version 18.04.3

Command outputs (note, typing this on a phone):

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet6 <IPv6address1> prefix 64 scopeid 0x0
inet6 <IPv6address2> prefix 64 scopeid 0x20
ether <macHere> ...
```

point is, ethernet iface is up, but no IPv4 listed. Only other interface is `lo`.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static #Ive tried dhcp here in place of static, without the following lines

address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Router gateway is 192.168.1.1, I've double checked

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 <hostname>

::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` is managed by `systemd-resolved` so I would prefer not to manually edit this

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53 #??? Don't understand why this is
options edns0
```

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
...
Link 2 (enp3s0)
  Current Scopes: none
  LLMNR setting: yes
  MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSSEC setting: no
  DNSSEC supported: no
```

`ip route show` and `ip route list` do not print anything to stdout

Please let me know what I can do to fix this issue. I can edit this post with more output if needed

**EDIT:** While the potential duplicate question is similar, it does not provide a solution on how to connect to the internet with the tools available on the system (aka netplan). That question is asking how to switch back to `etc/network/interfaces`, and the currently accepted answer is to `apt install ifupdown` (which is a brilliant idea considering networking is unavailable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04: switch back to /etc/network/interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces)

Comment: Rather than encourage poor ExecutionByFork to revert to ifup/down, I recommend that we instead tell him/her the new way: netplan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, ifup/down, implemented by `/etc/network/interfaces`, is replaced by `netplan`. Therefore, please revert the faulty entries. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Take out all the entries except:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>) the text editor.

Next, let's clean up your netplan file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.101/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation and spacing. Please proofread carefully twice. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

After these changes, reboot and let us see:

```
ip addr show
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. I have to say I much prefer the old method than netplan, and I had never even heard of the tool until now. But I suppose it's never a bad thing to learn something new