# cannot find /etc/network/interfaces file, doesn't exist

Tags: networking, 20.04, interface, default

First of all sorry if the question is unnecessary, I'm still a newbie.

In my ubuntu 20.04 install, I want to see the /etc/network/interfaces file, yet it doesn't exist.

This is the content of my /etc/network/ directory:

```
XXXXX@XXXXX-MS-7B79:/etc/network$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 abr 23 09:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 141 root root 12288 ago 20 06:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 ago  5 23:48 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 ago  6 20:11 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 ago  6 20:11 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 ago  5 23:48 if-up.d
```

Does this mean that I have to personally create the interfaces file? Each tutorial I read talks like it already exists automatically.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The tutorials that your are reading are obsolete.

Comment: Although Ubuntu has chosen not to use ifupdown any longer, it is still maintained and plenty modern. Obsolete is not the correct term, rather, you mean it's no longer the default. If you want to use your tutorial @tr3x just do ''sudo apt install ifupdown'' and there ya go. You may also want to install ''resolvconf'' so you can manually update your resolver and ''apt remove netplan''. Related answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces

Answer (score 3):

The file you're looking for does not exist anymore for new installations of Ubuntu versions 17.10 and up. Ubuntu 17.10 switched from ifupdown (which uses the /etc/network/interfaces file) to netplan. You can find configuration examples and documentation on [netplan.io](https://netplan.io).