# IP Camera V380 app

Tags: camera

I have an IP Camera that works on v380 app for mobile phones haven't tried any web-base application before and was wondering if there is an alternative software for Ubuntu users. My IP camera does not use IP but rather a specific cam ID (I don't actually see any IP address in the config settings but the device says its an IP Camera)

Comment: It probably has a web interface you could use, if you can find its IP address. Otherwise I'm not sure. Check with the manufacturer what protocols it provides.

Comment: i did tried looking for a web interface until now but no success there. The device is a cheap china made but actually performs good. I could only view it using the app on my mobile phone it would be better if I could view it using my PC

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to find out IP address of the camera:

   If that camera plugs into your home router via ethernet or connects to WiFi , it has to have LAN IP  address.  Probably it's on default IP address, so find the default IP for the brand of this camera.
2. Create alias address for your laptop.

   Once you find camera's IP we now need to make the laptop and IP camera talk to each other.  They need to have an address on the same network/subnet. Suppose your laptop connects to the network via ethernet interface labeled `eth0` (which is an older interface naming scheme; [newer releases of Ubuntu use systemd which uses very different naming scheme](https://askubuntu.com/a/704364/295286)). It currently uses IP address 192.168.1.5 and the camera's default IP is 192.168.1.105 They are on the same network 192.168.1.0 and they can talk. Go to next step. Otherwise, if IP camera's address is something else like 10.0.0.105 - create an alias address. There's more than one way to do that. One is using `ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.5 netmask 225.225.225.0` and more modern way is `ip addr add 10.0.0.5/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1`. Both of these ways are not permanent and will exist until the next reboot. Permanent way depends on what your Ubuntu uses for networking. Most recent releases of Ubuntu use netplan, which [apparently doesn't support alias IP addresses](https://askubuntu.com/a/995719/295286).
3. Stream from IP camera in VLC

   IP cameras use RTSP protocol for streaming video. Typically, they use port 554 and specific path. Address of the camera stream would be something like `rtsp://10.0.0.105:554/profile1/media.smp` Consult your IP camera's manufacturer documentation on what that path after 554 should be. You can try just `/` - a lot of IP cameras support that. Now in VLC player (which you should already have installed) click Media -> Open Network Stream and place the RTSP address of your camera there. Click play.

There are other video players out there, so VLC is just one example. I don't endorse it in any way.